# C# & NodeJS PBKDF Encryption

Tags: c#, node.js, pbkdf2

im making a website and a desktop application, they both will use the same database but i need them to generate the same hashes, how can i do this with NodeJS and C#?

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync('pass', 'saltsaltsaltsalt', 100000, 64, 'sha256').toString('base64');
console.log(key);
```

```
Output: lLRnCThEdyMUjj6QazuIBvI/hRv7bT4r9Z5FKJ39NOOmFvI+5V5YhqTxInWCi3D8rOB1eMGV/Yn71m597/bzWw==
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class Program
{
    private const int HashIterations = 100000;
    public static void Main()
    {
        var password = "pass";
        var salt = "saltsaltsaltsalt";
        var xx = GeneratePasswordHash(password, salt);
        Console.WriteLine(xx);
    }

    public static string GeneratePasswordHash(string password, string salt, int hashIterations = HashIterations)
    {
        byte[] hash;
        using (var crypto = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Convert.FromBase64String(salt), hashIterations))
        {
            hash = crypto.GetBytes(64);
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }
}
```

```
Output: 0Nj5NJWM8dtAFFUU8T3UUQhmdNIbKTLndqjqXzkulEXRVsjlIb28C00daPi96pDk+evKY3CLbkLOGVZUuNiimQ==
```

what im expecting and need is both these programs to output the same hash.

Comment: Ok - you're going to have to do better than that - You've asked for two sides of an example, yet have only produced half of what's required - what are the outputs either? Why do you need two implementations? Why do you need two? There are extra args in nodeJS example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899014/how-do-i-use-sha-512-with-rfc2898derivebytes-in-my-salt-hash-code

Comment: i have a desktop app which is in C# and my website which is in NoeJS, a user can login to the site or the app on the same account, todo this i need to compare the stored hash with the login inputted password hash, but node and c# is giving me different hashes for the same password and salt. i dont know C# so im here on stackoverflow for help.

Comment: If you know Node - you could just have a node endpoint which returns a hash, given a password? DRY and that? Also one source of truth . But that doesn't help your problem - have you got sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: i added the outputs and added to the code, please go check it out

Comment: You are Base64 decoding your salt. If you’ve specified it as a string in your JavaScript code I believe the library takes the UTF8 encoding, not the base64 decoding.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48468801/783912) there is a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation) that enables the use of PBKDF2 in c#.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-3.1) you can use it like this:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation;
```

```cs
var password = "pass";
var salt = "saltsaltsaltsalt";
string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
            password: password,
            salt: Convert.FromBase64String(salt),
            prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
            iterationCount: 10000,
            numBytesRequested: 64));
Console.WriteLine(hashed);
```

I can currently not verify that this gives you the same hash as your NodeJS code.